# How to route dynamic URL in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

Say I have the following URL:

```
/page?name=myname&age=25
```

Where name and age have dynamic values.

How do I construct a router get function for this page?

Option 1:

```
router.route("/page").get(function(req, res) {
    console.log("got page");
}
```

Option 2:

```
router.route("/page?name&age").get(function(req, res) {
    console.log("got page");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be

```
router.route("/page").get(function(req, res) {
    console.log("got page");
}
```

?name=myname&age=25  => are req parameters. which can be accessed by

```
req.query.name
req.query.age
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the route for the page as:

```
router.route("/page").get(function(req, res) {
    console.log("got page");
}
```

and as for the query parameters you can access them as:

`req.query.YOUR_QUERY_NAME`

therefore in your case it will become `req.query.name` and `req.query.age` which will return the values "myname" and 25 respectively.

you can read more on [Documentation page](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query)

In case you are also having or planning to have  routes like:
`http://localhost:3000/name/user/age/84`

In that case you can have you routes config as:

```
router.route("/name/:myName/age/:myage").get(function(req, res) {
name = req.params.myName;
age = req.params.myage;
});
```

as `req.params` returns the object with value params here req.params if `console.log` will return `{"myName":"user", "myage":"84"}` object

you can read more about route params from [Route params link](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `req.query.name` and `req.query.age` for that, you don't need a specific route, just `router.route("/page")...`

You can also use: [Route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) to get a clean URL